# Installing Inotify with NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, osx-lion

I'm quite new to nodeJS and I'm trying to install a package called inotify using the Node Package Manager (NPM).

After installing NPM (on OSX Lion), I tried to install inotify with the command:

> sudo npm install inotify

And I get the following error:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inotify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inotify

> inotify@0.2.2 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/inotify
> node-waf configure build

Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for node path                   : not found 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.6.6 
Checking for program node                : /usr/local/bin/node 
Checking for function inotify_init       : not found 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/inotify/src/wscript:11: error: the configuration failed (see '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/inotify/build/config.log')
npm ERR! error installing inotify@0.2.2

npm ERR! inotify@0.2.2 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the inotify@0.2.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the inotify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-waf configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls inotify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "inotify"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/username/code
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.6
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message inotify@0.2.2 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! message `sh "-c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/code/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Can someone help me out with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inotify module won't build because it can't find `inotify_init`. This is because inotify is not available on OS X.

The FSEvents API on OS X provides similar functionality, but it's a completely different API. The inotify module is not going to work in this situation.

Depending on what you are trying to do, [`fs.watch`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) might suit your needs. It abstracts away platform differences:

> - On Linux systems, this uses `inotify`.
> - On BSD systems (including OS X), this uses `kqueue`.
> - On SunOS systems (including Solaris and SmartOS), this uses event ports.
> - On Windows systems, this feature depends on `ReadDirectoryChangesW`.